# How do I change the order of XmlElements?

Tags: xml, powershell, element, xmlelement

I have an XML that has various elements, but one of them named `RowId`, I'd like to move to the top of the respective XML array...essentially sorting the elements in my way. My below code can be copied/pasted for you to test with.

1. What's the best way to accomplish this? And/or is there a better way than what I'm doing now? This seems clumsy.
2. Why does the below code **work** if I include `| Sort-Object -Property "Name"`?

Copy & Paste below code:

```
$rawXML = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Document">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Object1" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Element1" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Element2" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="-1"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="RowId">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Object2" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="Element4" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="80"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="Element5" nillable="true">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="-1"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="RowId">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="20"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
"@

$rawXML.schema.element.complexType.sequence.element.complexType.sequence | ForEach-Object {
    $sequence = $_

    # This does NOT work
    $childNodes = $sequence.ChildNodes #| Sort-Object -Property "Name"

    $childNodes.Count # Output = 3
    $sequence.RemoveAll()
    $childNodes.Count # Output = 0

    
    # This DOES work; Only difference is '| Sort-Object -Property "Name"'
    <#
    $childNodes = $sequence.ChildNodes | Sort-Object -Property "Name"

    $childNodes.Count # Output = 3
    $sequence.RemoveAll()
    $childNodes.Count # Output = 3
    #>

    $childNodes | ForEach-Object {
        $child = $_
        if ($child.Name -eq "RowId") {
            $sequence.InsertBefore($child, $sequence.FirstChild)

        } else {
            $sequence.AppendChild($child) | out-null
        }
        
    }
}

$rawXML.InnerXml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recap what you've already attempted *in principle*: In oder to modify the XML DOM stored in `$rawXML` directly, you need to use the [`[xml]` (`System.Xml.XmlDocument`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument) .NET type's own methods.

The following simplified approach locates the child element of interest first and then uses `.InsertBefore()` to move it to the top (there is no  need to *remove* the element being moved before inserting it):

```sh
$rawXML.schema.element.complexType.sequence.element.complexType.sequence | ForEach-Object {
  
  # Find the child element whose 'name' attribute is 'RowId'
  $rowIdElem = $_.ChildNodes.Where({ $_.name -eq 'RowId' })[0]

  # Insert the row-ID element before the currently first child element,
  # which effectively moves it to the top.
  $null = $_.InsertBefore($rowIdElem, $_.FirstChildNode)

}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `$childNodes = $sequence.ChildNodes` effectively makes `$childNodes` point to the *live list of child nodes* stored in the element's `.ChildNodes` property (which is of a type derived from [`System.Xml.XmlNodeList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNodeList))
- Therefore, after calling `$sequence.ChildNodes.Clear()` to remove all child nodes, both `$sequence.ChildNodes` and `$childNodes` refer to an *empty collection*, i.e. there's *nothing to enumerate*, which is why the `ForEach-Object` script block (`$childNodes | ForEach-Object { ... }` ) is never called.
- By contrast, by involving a `Sort-Object` call (`$childNodes = $sequence.ChildNode | Sort-Object Name`), you're enumerating the child elements right there and then, and capturing a *snapshot* of the child elements *as an independent array* (a regular PowerShell array of type `[object[]]`), whose elements *are* enumerated as expected later, causing the `ForEach-Object` call for reattaching the elements in custom order to work as expected.

Comment: Marting pointed out that it's returning `XmlNodeList` instead of an array. Just casting via `[Array]` makes my original code work.

Answer (score 1):

I think DOM NodeLists are "live" collections in normal DOM use ("live" I think was the spec term in the W3C spec, the Microsoft docs calls them dynamic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/dynamic-updates-to-nodelists-and-namednodemaps) so your attempt `$childNodes = $sequence.ChildNodes` stores that live NodeList in a variable and as such a collection it reflects any change to the DOM tree. The Powershell use of piping that collection to `Sort-Object` with `$sequence.ChildNodes | Sort-Object -Property "Name"` does not return an XmlNodeList or other live/dynamic collection, rather it returns an array of objects, e.g. `XmlNode[]` or `object[]`, so that way your code works as you want it to work as you later process that array and not the XmlNodeList that tracked the changes to the DOM tree.

Comment: It seems like it acts as a pointer and I need to copy the `ChildNodes` somehow?

Comment: @WilliamYK, .NET has references, not pointers, but that is not the issue, once you use the `Sort-Object` on the XmlNodeList you no longer have one stored in the newly assigned variable `$childNodes = $sequence.ChildNodes | Sort-Object -Property "Name"` but only an array of objects that are `XmlNode`s so you can iterate over such an array as it doesn't track changes in the DOM tree.

Comment: According to your logic, just casting the return value (`$childNodes = [Array]$sequence.ChildNodes`) should make my original code work...which it does work now. I can only choose one answer but I can upvote. Thanks for the help!